# Java process have memory leak

Tags: java

I have one Java process,now used 1.2GB memory
I use jmap dump a heap.bin,use memory analyzer check ,memory only used 2.4MB
ow to find which object used 1.2GB memory?

Details
Size: 2.4 MB Classes: 1.2k Objects: 57.9k Class Loader: 66 Unreachable Objects Histogram

```
Class Name                                                                         | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap | Percentage
class java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches @ 0xe1a3f9c0 System Class                   |           16 |       765,096 |     30.94%
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0xe55872d0                                      |           72 |       390,664 |     15.80%
org.jdom.Element @ 0xe55a4dc8                                                      |           32 |       343,472 |     13.89%
class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.XMLChar @ 0xe18fe228 System Class    |           40 |        65,592 |      2.65%
sun.nio.cs.ext.ExtendedCharsets @ 0xe55acab0                                       |           32 |        64,800 |      2.62%
sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader @ 0xe55ab718                                      |           72 |        51,792 |      2.09%
sun.text.resources.LocaleElements @ 0xe5552a28                                     |           24 |        50,824 |      2.06%
class java.lang.System @ 0xe155feb0 System Class                                   |           24 |        43,392 |      1.75%
class sun.nio.cs.ext.Big5$Decoder @ 0xe193aab8 System Class                        |           32 |        34,840 |      1.41%
class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EncodingMap @ 0xe1911970 System Class|            8 |        30,496 |      1.23%
sun.text.resources.DateFormatZoneData @ 0xe5552a10                                 |           24 |        25,368 |      1.03%
java.io.PrintStream @ 0xe5592940                                                   |           32 |        25,088 |      1.01%
class java.beans.Introspector @ 0xe1766b10 System Class                            |           64 |        23,424 |      0.95%
class $Proxy1 @ 0xe1b28eb0                                                         |          312 |        23,368 |      0.94%
java.lang.String[560][] @ 0xe55889c0                                               |        2,256 |        20,176 |      0.82%
class sun.security.jca.Providers @ 0xe1a52ed8 System Class                         |           24 |        16,240 |      0.66%
class java.nio.charset.Charset @ 0xe15d5b60 System Class                           |           40 |        12,184 |      0.49%
auo.beol.hisloader.BeolHisLoader @ 0xe55b5848  Thread-4 Thread                     |          160 |        12,064 |      0.49%
auo.beol.hisloader.RecoverHisLoader @ 0xe5651018  Thread-3 Thread                  |          160 |        11,976 |      0.48%
org.jdom.Element @ 0xe55b1520                                                      |           32 |        11,776 |      0.48%
org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender @ 0xe55a3350                                  |           72 |        11,512 |      0.47%
org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender @ 0xe5587d20                                  |           72 |        11,472 |      0.46%
org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender @ 0xe5587e50                                      |           56 |        11,320 |      0.46%
class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.Constants @ 0xe1909fa8 System Class  |          528 |        11,072 |      0.45%
org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender @ 0xe55a3590                                  |           72 |        11,000 |      0.44%
org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender @ 0xe559b220                                  |           72 |        10,968 |      0.44%
class $Proxy0 @ 0xe1aefcb0                                                         |          160 |        10,672 |      0.43%
auo.cim.util.log.LogThreadData @ 0xe55a44b0                                        |           32 |         8,920 |      0.36%
auo.cim.util.log.LogThreadData @ 0xe5651130                                        |           32 |         8,920 |      0.36%
auo.cim.util.log.LogThreadData @ 0xebf5a038                                        |           32 |         8,920 |      0.36%
Total: 30 of 3,146 entries; 3,116 more                                             |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to view the heapdump visually by using a tool such as http://visualvm.java.net/heapdump.html

Answer (score 0):

There must be an object which is holding references and it might be causing memory leak. If you have heap dump, you can see which type has the most objects and search for the object which is holding references to them. Then you should inspect your code, and find lines which are causing memory leak problem.

Maybe this link will help : 
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/monitoring-and-detecting-memory-leaks-in-your-java-application.html

Also there is nice tool named MAT : http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

It helped me to fix memory problems.